# How to unlock files for Deletion after merging PDFs together

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

**Update**

See the answer for the complete solution.

---

I have now updated the code so that the last few lines read:

```
       reader.Close();
        f++;
        if (f >= orderedList.Count) continue;
        reader = new PdfReader(targetFolder + orderedList[f]);
        // we retrieve the total number of pages
        n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        pdfNewPageFlag = true;
       reader.Close();
    }
}
```

And the documents are successfully completed, but the final PDF is corrupted (I'm assuming because it hasn't been closed properly)

---

As part of a Word-to-PDF convert and merge process, I am running the following method to merge all PDFs into 1 super-PDF ( with `iTextSharp.text.pdf`):

```
    public void Pdfs(string targetPdf, List<string> orderedList, string targetFolder, string spSite)
    {
        var f = 0;
        // we create a reader for a certain document
        var reader = new PdfReader(targetFolder + orderedList[f]);
        // we retrieve the total number of pages
        var n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        
        // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(targetPdf, FileMode.Create));
        // step 3: we open the document
        document.Open();
        var cb = writer.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page;
        int rotation;
        // step 4: we add content
        var pdfPageName = 0;
        var pdfNewPageFlag = true;
        while (f < orderedList.Count)
        {
            var i = 0;
            while (i < n)
            {
                i++;
                document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                document.NewPage();
                if (pdfNewPageFlag)
                {
                    var chapter = new iTextSharp.text.Chapter(orderedList[pdfPageName], pdfPageName + 1);
                    document.Add(chapter);
                    pdfNewPageFlag = false;
                    pdfPageName++;
                }

                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);

                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            f++;
            if (f >= orderedList.Count) continue;
            reader = new PdfReader(targetFolder + orderedList[f]);
            // we retrieve the total number of pages
            n = reader.NumberOfPages;
            pdfNewPageFlag = true;
        }

        // step 5: we close the document
        document.Close();
    }
```

This method also creates a bookmark at the beginning of each original document. Once the documents have all been merged, I am calling this method to delete the files:

```
    private static void DeletePdfs()
    {
        // Delete the files
        foreach (var file in orderedListPdfFileNames)
        {
            var newFileName = tempfolder + file;
            File.Delete(newFileName);
        }
    }
```

But when trying to actually delete the file, I am seeing this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file '\file\IT\SK\test\HrDocs\Cover.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

In the `PDFs` method, I have tried calling `writer.Close()` and `reader.Close()` both before and after `document.Close()`, but then I get the message `Cannot close a document which is already closed`.

Is anyone able to help out with this or point me in the right direction? I can't seem to figure out which part of the Merge process is locking the files!

Comment: Consider closing all your `PdfReader` instances.

Comment: @mkl I added `reader.Close();` directly after `pdfNewPageFlag = true;`, but then `document.Close();` returns an error (the file is already closed)! if I remove `document.Close();` then it errors on deletion!

Comment: @mkl It seems that after changing the code as I did in my answer, the final PDF appears to be corrupted and I am unable to open it! There is still something missing from this

Comment: yes, you definitively have to close the `document` and also all `PdfReader` instances. And if closing the readers *before* the document doesn't work, you'll have to close them *thereafter*. Collect all readers you opened in a list for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was just a case of not closing the readers in the right places.

As mkl mentioned in the comments, if `document.Close()` fails after closing the readers, then I need to close the readers afterwards.

In the below amendment I added each reader to a list after creation and they are all closed at the end:

```
    public void Pdfs(string targetPdf, List<string> orderedList, string targetFolder, string spSite)
    {
        var readerlist = new List<PdfReader>();

        var f = 0;
        // we create a reader for a certain document
        var reader = new PdfReader(targetFolder + orderedList[f]);
        readerlist.Add(reader);

        // we retrieve the total number of pages
        var n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

        // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(targetPdf, FileMode.Create));
        // step 3: we open the document
        document.Open();
        var cb = writer.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page;
        int rotation;
        // step 4: we add content
        var pdfPageName = 0;
        var pdfNewPageFlag = true;
        while (f < orderedList.Count)
        {
            var i = 0;
            while (i < n)
            {
                i++;
                document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                document.NewPage();
                if (pdfNewPageFlag)
                {
                    var chapter = new iTextSharp.text.Chapter(orderedList[pdfPageName], pdfPageName + 1);
                    document.Add(chapter);
                    pdfNewPageFlag = false;
                    pdfPageName++;
                }

                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);

                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }
            }

            f++;
            if (f >= orderedList.Count) continue;
            reader = new PdfReader(targetFolder + orderedList[f]);
            readerlist.Add(reader);

            // we retrieve the total number of pages
            n = reader.NumberOfPages;
            pdfNewPageFlag = true;
        }

        // step 5: we close the document
        document.Close();

        foreach (var rdr in readerlist)
        {
            rdr.Close();
        }
    }
```